# Spanning sets: ambiguous definition

Tags: linear-algebra

Second question within 20 minutes - sorry about that! But, I've encountered another hiccup in a linear algebra textbook:

"We define a set of vectors $S$ in a vector space $V$ as a spanning set for $V$ if every vector in V can be written as a linear combination of the vectors in $S$, that is, if $V= \text{span}\text{{S}}$

If we go by their "sentence" definition (i.e. every vector in V can be written as a linear combination of the vectors in S), wouldn't that be $V \subseteq \text{span}\text{{S}}$?

What is the generally accepted definition?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The definition you have given really means that $V$ is a subset of the span, but the opposite inclusion holds trivially since there is closure under addition and scalar multiplication.

Answer (score 6):

True. However, $S\subseteq V$, and linear combinations of vectors in $V$ (like those in $S$) are again vectors in $V$. Hence, we automatically have $V\supseteq\text{span} S,$ too.

Comment: Both great and quick answers. I'm going to pick yours since you were a bit quicker.

Comment: Actually, it looks like Jacob answered about a minute before I did, but you can certainly upvote both of them, and accept whichever of them that you want.

Comment: I upvoted both. I will accept Jacob's.